# Wordpress custom hierarchy of breadcrumbs (and no hierarchy of slug / URLs)

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

I am trying to create a hierarchy of pages in Wordpress for the breadcrumbs. The simplest way to do it, is by using the "[Parent Page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-options/#parent-page)" attribute. However, when using this feature, it also creates a hierarchy in the slugs (which means that change in the hierarchy requires to maintain a list of 301's and changing the internal links in the website).

For example, let's say that I have to following hierarchy:

> - Water
>
>   - Glass of Water
>   - Bottled Water
> - Fire
>
>   - Light a Fire

The URL for the Glass of Water page will be: `/water/glass-of-water/`. how can I keep all the slugs "flat", while still have the hierarchy in the breadcrumbs (in this case `Home > Water > Glass of Water` and keep the url `/glass-of-water`)?

I found many WP websites that use this practice. For example the following post in the Yoast SEO website:

https://yoast.com/what-is-storytelling-and-why-should-you-use-it/

Has the following breadcrumbs:
`Home » SEO blog » Content SEO » What is storytelling and why should you use it?`

How can I set a custom breadcrumb hierarchy both for pages and for posts, regardless of the slug?

I use the latest version of Wordpress (Currently 5.3.X), with Yoast SEO plugin, the free version. If needed, I will install other plugins (free of paid), however I am trying to avoid plugins that are not popular or don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue a few days before I have one solution to create a breadcrumb.
Yoast Provides The Facility to create breadcrumb.

Code:

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
}
?>
```

[image]

here is link.

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-add-breadcrumbs-to-your-wordpress-website